# RabbitMq Exception on web application

Tags: java, tomcat, rabbitmq

I developed a project using RabbitMq to communicate between a consumer and a producer. While I was developing the project I tested the functionality from a simple test file and RabbitMq worked just fine. When I try to use the framework from a web page (using tomcat) it doesn't work anymore.

Any solutions?

Comment: The details of your client and server are not clear. Could it be that your server expects to use AMQP over TLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the library "amqp-client-3.0.4" (or any other version you are using) to the folder containing your apache tomcat instalation, usually C:\apache-tomcat\lib